# Laravel bitly error The response does not contain a shortened link

Tags: laravel

I use pacakage :: https://github.com/Shivella/laravel-bitly

I try to create bitly link 5000 link but It's always error :The response does not contain a shortened link

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $barcode = Barcode1::whereNull('shortlink')->get();
        foreach ($barcode as $b) {
            $url = app('bitly')->getUrl('https://www.test.com/shrotern/'.$b->encode);
            $update = Barcode1::find($b->id);
            $update->shortlink = $url;
            $update->save();
        }
    }
    return view('test');
}
```

How can I fix this

Comment: Have you tried a real domain which sends a 200 response instead of a 404?

Comment: no not yet i'll try

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine on a real domain or you can create a virtual host.

Comment: this is not an answer